# Pass the name of an array in command line to reference the array in a function

Tags: bash, array, bash-array

I'm trying to learn more bash by updating my bash_profile so that I can quickly do some adb commands that I usually have to copy-paste.  I found I was creating many similar functions that all looked like this:

```
function andVid() {
  minInputs=0
  fileName="$(filNamInc $MEDIA_DIR/Videos/aaaAndroidVideo mp4)"
  origCmd="adb shell screenrecord --time-limit 60 /sdcard/screenrecord.mp4; sleep 3; adb pull /sdcard/screenrecord.mp4 $fileName"
  cmd="$(andAddSer $minInputs "$origCmd" "$@")"
  echo "Use ctrl+c to stop recording"
  eval $cmd
}
```

Usually, when I see a bunch of similar functions, I try to combine them into 1 function.  So I made a function that would accept an array of arguments and would do the same actions just dependent on the array:

```
andVid=(4 'adb shell screenrecord --time-limit 60 /sdcard/screenrecord.mp4; sleep 3; adb pull /sdcard/screenrecord.mp4' '/Videos/aaaAndroidVideo' 'mp4')

function adbRnr() {
  minInputs=$1
  cmd=$2
  if (( $# > 3 )); then
    fileTarget=$3
    fileExtension=$4
    fileName="$(filNamInc $MEDIA_DIR$fileTarget $fileExtension)"
    cmd="$cmd $fileName"
  fi
  if (( $# > $minInputs )); then
    cmd="${cmd:0:4} -s ${@: -1} ${cmd:4}"
  fi
  eval $cmd
```

(Note: here you see what andAddSer was doing in the first function.)  This means that in order to run the function, you need to use a command line entry like this:

```
adbRnr "${andVid[@]}"
```

Which is both slow to type and hard to remember.  I'd rather enter just the name of the array, and then do the whole "${[@]}" part once it's in the function, such that the command line input would look like this:

```
adbRnr andVid
```

However... passing the array name has proved a significant problem.  I've tried pretty much every combination of calling the argument with "!", and it hasn't worked.  Example:

```
andVid=(4 'adb shell screenrecord --time-limit 60 /sdcard/screenrecord.mp4; sleep 3; adb pull /sdcard/screenrecord.mp4' '/Videos/aaaAndroidVideo' 'mp4')

function arrayParser() {
  echo "${andVid[*]}"    # echos as expected
  echo $#                # echos "1" as expected
  param=$1               
  echo $param            # echos "andVid" as expected
  cmd=("${!param[3]}")
  echo $cmd              # expected "mp4", nothing printed
}

arrayParser andVid
```

I know that you can't just pass arrays to functions in bash, but the array I'm referencing is already part of the profile.  How do I reference the array using the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a name reference variable in the function:

```
arrayParser () {
    declare -n arr="$1"

    printf 'Array: %s\n' "${arr[*]}"
    printf 'Array element at index 3: %s\n' "${arr[3]}"
}

myarray=( alpha beta gamma "bumbling bee" )
arrayParser myarray
```

Inside the function, any reference to the name reference variable `arr` will reference the variable passed to the function as its 1st argument.

Name reference variables were introduced in `bash` release 4.3.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I had to update bash on my OSX machine, so I am a bit concerned about issues due to that down the line, but it made all my functions work so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ .  Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
andVid=(4 'adb shell screenrecord --time-limit 60 /sdcard/screenrecord.mp4; sleep 3; adb pull /sdcard/screenrecord.mp4' '/Videos/aaaAndroidVideo' 'mp4')

param=andVid
cmd="\${$param[3]}"
eval echo "$cmd"
```